# Exclude DOM elements from knockout apply binding?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dom, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I want to target my knockout viewmodel to certain section of the dom as thus:

```
ko.applyBindings(MyViewModel,$('#Target')[0]);
```

However I do NOT want it to apply to all the doms below it. The reason for this is that the whole SPA thing isn't working very well - can't keep up with the jumbo sized viewmodel that results from including every potential interaction into one giant object. Hence, the page is composed of multiple partial views. I want each partials to instantiate its own ViewModel and provide interface for the parent to interact with.

Some sample dom

```
<div id="Target">
     <!--Everything here should be included except-->
     <div data-bind="DoNotBindBelowThis:true">
          <!--Everything here should NOT be included by the first binding, 
              I will specifically fill in the binding with targetted
              ApplyBind eg. ko.applyBindings(MyOtherViewModel, $('#MyOtherTarget')[0])
              to fill the gaps-->
            <div id="MyOtherTarget">
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Again how can I exclude an entire dom tree below the div tagged with `DoNotBindBelowThis` from `applyBindings`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at the blog post here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html

Basically, you can create a custom binding like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.DoNotBindBelowThis = {
    init: function() {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't quite get it, shouldn't we return controlsDescendantBindings false, instead of true?

Comment: `controlsDescendantBindings: true` tells KO that we (this binding) will handle applying bindings to our children.  In the sample binding above that is all that is done, so the children are left alone.  Then, you can come back and call `ko.applyBindings` to a specific DOM element that lives inside of the element that has this binding.

Comment: RP - I stumbled across your blog posts the other day, and it really helped. I wrote a custom binding to render Backbone-style views: https://gist.github.com/johntron/8047929